# How to make a for loop test for matches between columns of different data frames and then save to a new data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop in R that will make a new data frame ("results") when values of a column ("areaName2") in one data frame (df2), matches the value in a column ("ISLAND") from a different data frame (df1). 
If there are no matches in the first column in df2, then I want it to move on to pair a second set of columns from df2 and df1 (df2:"areaName1 and df1:"ARCHIP"). Again, if there is a match, it should be printed in the new data frame. If again, there is no match, then I want it to move on the a third pair of columns (df2:"Country" and df1:"COUNTRY"). 
If all columns in df 2 are blank, then I would like to skip that row. 
If there is some information in one of the columns in df 2, but it doesn't match df1, I would like it to state that somehow if that is possible.

I have made an example of df1, df2, and results:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5, 6)
COUNTRY <- c("country1", 'country2', 'country3','country4', 'country5', 'country6')
ARCHIP <- c('archipelago1', 'archipelago2', 'archipelgao3', 'archipelago4', 'archipelago5', 'archipelago6')
ISLAND <- c('someisland1', 'someIsland2', 'someIsland3', 'someIsland4', 'someIsland5', 'someIsland6')
df1 <- data.frame(ID, COUNTRY, ARCHIP, ISLAND)


Sciname <- c("scientificName1", "scientificName2", "scientificName3", "scientificName4", "scientificName5", "scientificName6")
AreaName2 <- c("someIsland1", NA, "someIsland3", NA, NA, 'unrecognisableIsland')
AreaName1 <- c("archipelago1", "archipelago2", "archipelago3", NA, NA, 'archipelago6')
Country <- c("country1", "country2", "country3", 'country4', NA, 'country6')
df2 <- data.frame(Sciname, Country, AreaName1, AreaName2)


Species <- c("scientificName1","scientificName2", "scientificName3", "scientificName4", 'scientificName6')
Location <- c("someIsland1", "archipelago2", "someIsland3", 'country4', 'UNREGOGNISED')
results <- data.frame(Species, Location)
```

I was thinking that I need to do something along the lines of this for each column set

```
for (i in df2$AreaName2) {
results[[i]] <- if(df2$AreaName2 %in% df1$ISLAND)
}
```

But I am not sure how to make it work for each set, or how to make it run though several columns - maybe I should make a for loop for each of the sets of columns I wish to match? 
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
# I like to use tidyverse :)
library(tidyverse)

# First, to create our datasets - (Thank you for providing sample data!)
# I've set this up in a slightly different way, in an attempt to keep our workspace clear.
# I've also used tibble in place of data.frame, to line up with the tidyverse approach.
df1 <- tibble(    ID = seq(1:6), 
                  COUNTRY = c("country1", 'country2', 'country3','country4', 'country5', 'country6'), 
                  ARCHIP = c('archipelago1', 'archipelago2', 'archipelgao3', 'archipelago4', 'archipelago5', 'archipelago6'), 
                  ISLAND = c('someIsland1', 'someIsland2', 'someIsland3', 'someIsland4', 'someIsland5', 'someIsland6'))

df2 <- tibble(    Sciname = c("scientificName1", "scientificName2", "scientificName3", "scientificName4", "scientificName5", "scientificName6"), 
                  Country = c("country1", "country2", "country3", 'country4', NA, 'country6'), 
                  AreaName1 = c("archipelago1", "archipelago2", "archipelago3", NA, NA, 'archipelago6'),
                  AreaName2 = c("someIsland1", NA, "someIsland3", NA, NA, 'unrecognisableIsland'))


# Rather than use a for loop, I'll use full_join to match the two tables, then filter for the conditions you're looking for. 

# Merge data
join_country <- full_join(df2, df1, by = c("Country" = "COUNTRY"))

# Identify scinames with matching island names
# I use _f to signify my goal here - filtering
island_f <- join_country %>%
  filter(AreaName2 == ISLAND) %>%
  # Keep only relevant columns
  select(Sciname, Location = AreaName2)

# Identify scinames with matching archip names
archip_f <- join_country %>%
  filter(
         # Exclude scinames we've identified with matching island names.
         !(Sciname %in% island_f$Sciname),
         AreaName1 == ARCHIP) %>%
  select(Sciname, Location = AreaName1)

# Identify scinames left over (countries already matched from full_join)
country_f <- join_country %>%
  filter(
    # Exclude scinames we've identified with matching island or archip names.
         !(Sciname %in% island_f$Sciname),
         !(Sciname %in% archip_f$Sciname)) %>%
  select(Sciname, Location = Country)

sciname_location <- bind_rows(island_f, 
                              archip_f,
                              country_f) %>%
  arrange(Sciname)

# Finally, to identify records that are populated but don't match at all, we can use anti_join.
records_no_match <- anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("COUNTRY" = "Country"))
```

You can learn more about relational data from [R for Data Science, chapter 13.](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html)

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely see if I can use this method! Would I need to restructure the data frames containing my data with tibble() to work with tidyverse?

Comment: @MariaWagner Dataframes should work just fine here. :)

Tibbles are dataframes with some changes in old behavior to make life easier (see https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html for more information). They're typically interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution might be to prioritise the locations first, and then filter for the locations with the highest priority.
Just like Rebecca, I would opt for the tidyverse ;-)

```
library(tidyverse)

# Bring df2 into long format
df_long2 <- pivot_longer(df2, -Sciname) %>% 
    select(-name) %>% 
    mutate(value = replace_na(value, "UNRECOGNISED"))

# Bring df1 into long format
df_long1 <- pivot_longer(df1, -ID) %>% 
    select(-ID)

results <- df_long2 %>% 
    left_join(df_long1) %>% 
    # Prioritize names
    mutate(lvl = case_when(
        name == "ISLAND" ~ 1,
        name == "ARCHIP" ~ 2,
        name == "COUNTRY" ~ 3,
        is.na(name)~ 4
    )) %>% 
    # Group by name
    group_by(Sciname) %>% 
    # Filter for groups with lowest lvl/highest priority
    filter(lvl == min(lvl)) %>% 
    # Drop duplicate rows
    distinct() %>% 
    select(-name, -lvl) %>% 
    # Rename
    rename(Species = 1,
           Location = 2)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried both these methods, but ended up with slightly different results. I also found out that my df2 is not organised as well as I thought, so I need to look through the whole of df1 for matches instead of prioritizing them. I think I will end up writing a few functions to match the two df and then do a presence/absence thing. 
But thank you!